# "Batch Insert" inserts null value in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I dont know why after clicking the "Add Button", the items that needs to insert into the database is NULL.

so here's my controller

```
public function addItem(){
  $data = array(
   "item_ID"=>$_POST['item_ID'],
   "itemName"=>$_POST['itemName'],
   "itemDescription"=>$_POST['itemDescription'],
   "itemLink"=>$_POST['itemLink']
  );
  $orgID = $this->model->get_org();
  $this->model->insertItem($data,$orgID);
}
```

and here's my model

```
public function insertItem($data,$orgID){
  $this->db->insert('Items',$data);
  $getID=$this->db->insert_id();
  foreach($orgID as $temp):
    $Organization_ID = $_POST[$temp->OrganizationID];
  endforeach;
  $SkillReq=$this->input->post('0');
  $Skill_ReqID=$this->input->post();

  $insertdata = array();
  for($i=0; $i=count($orgID); $i++){
    $insertdata[]=array(
       'Skill_ReqID'=>$Skill_ReqID[$i],
       'OrganizationID'=>$Organization_ID[$i],
       'item_ID'=>$getID[$i],
       'SkillReq'=>$SkillReq[$i]
      );
     }
  $this->db->insert_batch('skillreqdept',$insertdata);
 }
```

it actually inserts the rows that had been counted in orgID but there is no data, only the Auto Incremented skill_reqID has in it.

Comment: What is the null variable in `'Skill_ReqID'=>null[$i],` ?

Comment: it is auto incremented in the database so there's nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please check this line, foreach($orgID as $temp):
    $Organization_ID = $_POST[$temp->OrganizationID];
  endforeach; i think it's not correct !!

Answer (score 1):

I thing the issue is with `Skill_ReqID'=>null[$i]`, I dont know what is `null` variable.

**Please try the following:**

```
public function insertItem($data,$orgID){

      $this->db->insert('Items',$data);
      $getID=$this->db->insert_id();
      foreach($orgID as $temp):
        $Organization_ID = $_POST[$temp->OrganizationID];
      endforeach;
      $SkillReq=$this->input->post('0');

      $insertdata = array();
      for($i=0; $i=count($orgID); $i++){
        $items=array(
           'OrganizationID'=>$Organization_ID[$i],
           'itemID'=>$getID[$i],
           'SkillReq'=>$SkillReq[$i]
           );

            array_push($insertdata, $items);
         }

      $this->db->insert_batch('skillreqdept',$insertdata);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, please try it

Comment: i replaced the null thngy in input->post(); and its still no value in the database

Comment: What field is null exactly?

Comment: all fields except the skill_reqID which happens to have AI in database

Answer (score 1):

Ya, it should be empty. Check your array `"`

```
public function addItem(){
  $data = array(
   'item_ID"=>$_POST['item_ID'], <== wrong wrapping 
   'itemName"=>$_POST['itemName'],
   'itemDescription"=>$_POST['itemDescription'],
   'itemLink"=>$_POST['itemLink']
  );
  $orgID = $this->model->get_org();
  $this->model->insertItem($data,$orgID);
}
```

If you're using proper IDE, it will highlight such a minor issues like this

[image]

---

As well `insertdata` is any predefined PHP tag/function ??

[image]

---

As well what is this `null[$i]` assign. I never heard of it.

---

Before do insert use `print_r` to check data is in the correct format or not. `print_r($insertdata); die;`

Comment: i think it's not the problem while this will not works at all and will produce an error

Comment: @MacBooc Error ?? uhh if **environment is production** or **error report turned off** ***you get empty screen***

Comment: i always use  $_POST['name_name']  with underscore and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: i forgot to put "$" before the insertdata and about the null thingy in the array, i changed it. It is autoincremented in the database.

Comment: i forgot to put "$" before the insertdata and about the null thingy in the array, i changed it since it is autoincremented in the database, it will automatically post id even if i dont put this "skill_reqID"=>null[$i] in the code